# Want to show random item title from one appointed category

Tags: joomla-3.x, category

I have following codes:

```
<?php foreach ($list as $item) : ?>
    <li<?php if ($id == $item->id && in_array($view, array('category', 'categories')) && $option == 'com_content') echo ' class="active"'; ?>>
        <?php $levelup = $item->level - $startLevel - 1; ?>
        <a href="<?php echo JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getCategoryRoute($item->id)); ?>">
        <?php echo $item->title; ?>
            <?php if ($params->get('numitems')) : ?>
                (<?php echo $item->numitems; ?>)
            <?php endif; ?>
        </a>
```

Could anyone tell how to random the title? And control the showing numbers?

Comment: Do you mean `shuffle($list)`?   What are you currently seeing as output? What output do you want?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I don't know where I should add shuffle($list) or rand();

For example, I have 4items in this category: item1, item2, item3, item4

Now, output:
item1, item2, item3, item4

I want to randomly output only 2 items, such as:
item2, item4

Comment: Before the `foreach()` seems sensible.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I don't know where I should add shuffle($list) or rand(); 

For example, I have 4items in this category: item1, item2, item3, item4 

Now, output: item1, item2, item3, item4 

I want to randomly output only 2 items, such as:
item2, item4

Comment: `<?php shuffle($list); foreach ($list as $item) : ?>`? I don't see the purpose of declaring `$levelup`.